# I need to collect demographic data based on location

Tags: database, dataset, bigdata, data-analysis, demographics

I need to collect demographic data based on location.
Is google provide this?, or any one know api provide this data?
anyone give me api to pull data from it?
and if not found that how to get this data from any other sources

Comment: Hi Loai! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: It seems like your question includes many questions. Also, it's asking for recommendations for things. Both of these things are grounds for your question being closed

Comment: also, it's unclear what sort of demographic data you might want, and on what population?